# iOS Swift Is it worth trying to remove objects from a Swift array when filtering?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a table view with 30 rows. There are 10000 data points that are ordered chronologically. Each table view cell pulls out about 300 data points based on a filter clause. I have not seen the equivalent of "removeObjectsInArray" for Swift arrays [removeObjects(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1413942-removeobjects)

- Do I need to convert/cast swift array into NSMutableArray to be able
  to remove objects from array?
- **Is it worth trying to remove objects
  from swift array?**

I'm not sure if Swift's treatment of arrays would re-allocate the entire array, causing a bigger performance hit then gained by reducing the array size.

Answer (score 1):

Better not to do some casting to do the things, which can be done with the pure swift approach.

Here is an example:

```
    var mainArraySwift: [String] = []
    mainArraySwift.append("a")
    mainArraySwift.append("b")
    mainArraySwift.append("c")
    mainArraySwift.append("d")
    mainArraySwift.append("e")
    print(mainArraySwift)

    var arrayToBeRemoved: [String] = []
    arrayToBeRemoved.append("a")
    arrayToBeRemoved.append("b")
    arrayToBeRemoved.append("c")
    print(arrayToBeRemoved)

    mainArraySwift.removeAll { (value) -> Bool in
        return arrayToBeRemoved.contains(value)
    }
    print(mainArraySwift)
```

Output is:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
["a", "b", "c"]
["d", "e"]
```

Not exact match to NSMutableArray's method, but this is something of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

The question as posed is much too broad / vague. You have not even given enough information to indicate what the problem is, i.e. why you think you need to remove anything from the data points array. If you want specific advice about efficiency, show the array (or at least describe it) and what each cell needs from it.

As far as *table views* go, the key piece of information you need to keep in mind is that a call to `cellForRowAt:` must be able to lay its hands on the data *instantly*. Thus, you should definitely not be doing any filtering in `cellForRowAt:` itself. You need to architect things so that there are always 30 arrays (or whatever) corresponding to your 30 rows, ready and waiting with the data for each row *instantly*.

But with regard to *how* to do that, you have given no information about the nature and form of the data points array or the filter operations, so it's impossible to say whether there is any efficiency to be gained in that area. Perhaps what you're doing is not inefficient. Perhaps an array is not the best data model. It's impossible to say, as you have given no information whatever. (You certainly should *not* cast to NSMutableArray for this purpose, though — whatever exactly the "purpose" may be.)